# Get-ACL with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, remote-access, acl

i have a problem with a PowerShell Command.

When i try this command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ... -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-Acl -Path "..."}
```

i get an access denied message.

When i try to execute the command on the local machine without Invoke-Command it works. I use the same Credentials for Invoke Command and to execute it on the local machine.

The Executionpolicy on the remote server is on: RemoteSigned

Commands like New-ADuser and so on works fine.

Does someone know how can i fix this?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: Access denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (....PATH....:String) [Get-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
    + PSComputerName        : .....

Cannot find path '...' because it does not exist 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ....